# AngularJS: Filter Table on ANY Combination of Checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter the display of rows in a table based on the values of 4 checkboxes -- I had it when the original specs stated that it was just one of the four values (I used radio buttons) but in the review it was changed to being any combination of the four -- if checked, the corresponding rows show and if unchecked, they don't. I don't know how to get there from here.

Here's the HTML:

```
<body style="padding:20px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Marketing" ng-model="Department" /> Marketing&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sales" ng-model="Department" /> Sales&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="Support" ng-model="Department" /> Support&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="Management" ng-model="Department" /> Management

    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Department</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="t in tickets | filter:{Department: t.Department}">
          <td>{{t.ID}}</td>
          <td>{{t.Title}}</td>
          <td>{{t.Department}}</td>
          <td>{{t.Status}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

and here's the script:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
      $scope.tickets = [
        {ID:'1', Title:'Kick Off Summer Campaign', Department:'Marketing', Status:'In Progress'},
        {ID:'2', Title:'Attend SummerConn', Department:'Sales', Status:'In Progress'},
        {ID:'3', Title:'Replace Ticketing Software', Department:'Support', Status:'In Progress'},
        {ID:'4', Title:'Read "The Salesman Within"', Department:'Sales', Status:'In Progress'},
        {ID:'5', Title:'Send Email 020', Department:'Marketing', Status:'In Progress'},
        {ID:'6', Title:'Refactor Training', Department:'Support', Status:'In Progress'},
        {ID:'7', Title:'Hire Call Center Coordinator', Department:'Management', Status:'In Progress'},
        {ID:'8', Title:'Send Email 044', Department:'Marketing', Status:'In Progress'},
        {ID:'9', Title:'Organize Convention Booths', Department:'Sales', Status:'In Progress'},
        {ID:'10', Title:'Send Email 123', Department:'Marketing', Status:'In Progress'},
      ];

    }); // end main controller
```

AND here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aloKUOjaX7NWzPicTdRO?p=preview)

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: One way would be to make use of a filter predicate: http://plnkr.co/edit/XPIjf40FLRCSzmIMtkfX?p=preview

Comment: brilliant! I didn't know about Filter Predicates (off to Google now). Can you make this an answer so I can Mark It?

Comment: I was just about to post this (relatively) elaborate custom filter as an answer, and there you just did it in four lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that you're able to supply predicate function to [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) and map each checkbox `ng-model` to separate values, which you can then use in your predicate.

```
$scope.checked = function(val) {
    return $scope.Department[val.Department];
};
```

Here's the demonstration [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XPIjf40FLRCSzmIMtkfX?p=preview).

Glad that helped.

Comment: I forgot one stipulation and can't figure out how to add it to you solution. If the user doesn't know which Department to choose and leaves it blank, the default value is 'Other' and I need it always checked and any Others should always show. I tried to add Department.Other == true but that didn't work

Comment: @jgravois I'm not sure from your wording here if you wish to support items with a `Department` value of `Other` and thus a corresponding checkbox, or if you simply wish for all your items to be displayed when no checkbox is ticked. Here's a suggested implementation for the latter case http://plnkr.co/edit/akttkEevUZOBCEEt7FYx?p=preview

Comment: It's actually the other case I need ... IF a ticket is in Department Other, it should show and then only show tickets in division that are checked (like it is now)

Comment: @jgravois it's simply a matter of modifying the logic in your filter predicate. The current item in the `ng-repeat` iteration gets passed to the predicate so you can access it in the function. If you need any further modifications, I'm sure you can figure it out. http://plnkr.co/edit/IoY5CiKQHwnTZyzUFXpn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you have to sort by status, then probably the best solution is to just create a separate, `filteredTickets` object in the controller, which gets updated when the checkboxes change. Use that with `ng-repeat` without the `filter` expression.

Comment: I have to sort by Status

Comment: Udated my answer accordingly.